# how to solve origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: django

Access to font at 'https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/ewan-space/ewan/static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

i see tihis erorr in django admin  when i collect my static in digitalochenspace , and it's work fine in when collect static in localhost,

this is my code
settings

```
#installed apps     
 "corsheaders",

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True
```

django 3.2
python 3.8

how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you try to add 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware' in MIDDLEWARE list?

Comment: I  cut my code to simple read , 
this is my middlewhere 
'MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]'